# php date return invalid hour

Tags: php, timezone, windows-server

This code `date("H:i")` return invalid hour:min for me.

Current time windows server 2016 is 10:55 But `date("H:i")` return 11:55  !?

My PHP version is 5.6.37 and install `timezonedb` extention but I still have this problem.

I set time zone to `Asia/Tehran` and get current value with `date_default_timezone_get()` everything all right.

[image]

Result PHP code:

[image]

Comment: Iran has recently changed their Daylight Saving Time. You probably need to update [the time zone database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) in your OS.

Answer (score 1):

I found the news here https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/iran-dst-2022.html, it says Iran has decided to cancel DST from 2023, so make sure you have  installed the [lastest timezonedb extension](https://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb/2023.3). You can check it with the following code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tehran');
echo date('I'); # should be 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Iran now has Daylight Saving Time, so I suggest you update your operating system, or use an external 3rd party service to get the current time.

get more information at [Official Time Zone Authority](https://www.iana.org/time-zones)